# Do I *need* `exit 0` at the end of `rc.local`?

Tags: debian, startup

What is the purpose of the exit code in `rc.local`? I seem to execute just fine without it.  The header shows:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local - executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel
#
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
```

Who checks the return code?  Does it default to 0 anyways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't say "always `exit 0`". Read it again without the line break.

> Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other value on error.

- To indicate success, exit 0.
- To indicate error, exit any other value.

There isn't necessarily anything that will check its status, but some init systems will display "[OK]" or "[FAIL]" on screen for the user. In any case, it's good practice to make sure your scripts exit with a meaningful return code.

The default exit status, like any other script, will be the exit status of the last command run in the script.

Comment: Nice. But the question still stands: what, if anything, checks that exit status?

Comment: What do you mean by "some init systems"?

Comment: sysv init on Linux did that for a while.

Comment: I misread the instruction as 'your script should always exit 0' too. Perhaps the comment could be reworded for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `exit 0` at the end of the script.

Run `locate rc.local | grep -vF /etc/rc.local` to find files that may be involved in calling /etc/rc.local and examining its exit code.

/etc/init.d/rc.local seems to be such an init script in my Xubuntu 15.10: It seems to get the exit code and log something using that value, if "$VERBOSE" variable is not "no".

You may put line `echo "$(ps -o args= $PPID)" >/tmp/caller` to /etc/rc.local, and it writes the caller's name in file /tmp/caller during boot. In my Xubuntu 15.10 system that is "/sbin/init persistent splash".

Answer (score -1):

rc.local is a script file you can put your script for last running command after linux up

rc.local doesn't provide a way to intelligently recover from errors. If any command fails, it stops running, exit 0 help if any error occur

Exit codes are a number between 0 and 255, which is returned by any Unix command when it returns control to its parent process.

Comment: If, indeed, `rc.local` execution stops on the first error, then `exit 0` won't help since it will only run if all preceding commands exit successfully. Do you mean perhaps that `exit 0` is there for the specific case where the file contains no commands at all? In any case, it would be nice to find authoritative references.

Comment: `rc.local` doesn't terminate on first failure.  It runs just like any other script would.

Comment: … any other script **with the `-e` option passed to the shell**, that is.  Read the first line of the script as given in the question.